# How to write a long date with datetimepicker values

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How can I make the datatimepicker component can write long date ?

In my case , I want to show the amount in words on a label.

```
label1.text = DTPicker1.value.ToString();
```

Example :

input : 13/07/2016 out: 13 de July de 2016

My dataPicker Properties :

```
CustomFormat : dd MMMM yyyy 
Format : Custom
```

But even with this setting the value remains 13/07/2016 09:50 AM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried passing a format as a parameter of the `ToString()` call?

Like the following:

```
label1.text = DTPicker1.value.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the date format to your `.ToString()` call:

```
label1.text = DTPicker1.value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Further information can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @downvoter care explaining why you downvoted?

Comment: Because you pretty much copy pasted the previously written answer ^^

Comment: @Zil well I wrote it while you were writing it aswell - I didnt copy a single line ;) Sorry if it looked like